# Can you push notifications directly from a Phonegap application instead of a server?

Tags: cordova, notifications

I'm currently pulling together some research for an upcoming project and from what I have gathered so far it appears that all notifications for Android, iPhone, etc. must be sent from a server. What was asked of me was to send the push notifications directly from the app itself. Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you talking about sending a notification from one device to a different device? Otherwise this sounds like a local notification and not a push notification.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Yes! Thank you, I could not easily find the term 'Local Notification' amid all the discussion of push notifications. That is exactly what I was looking for. If you put an answer in I will give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are asking about sending a notification from one device to another, I believe you are looking for `Local Notification` which is similar in display but triggered from a timed event on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a http interface that can be called from an Android device but it is safe to delegate this task to a common server. Security could be an issue if you delegate your app to store the both the registration-id and the API-KEY needed to send notifications. For IOS, if possible (I do not know), there is the same reason for not to do in that way.